# Why is my PHP code not being processed when I add it to a <textarea> using jQuery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wysiwyg

I have a problem with setting phtml in my jwysiwyg textarea. When I set up my HTML with code like this:

```
$("#txtarea").wysiwyg('setContent', somePHTML);
```

All PHP tags are commented and phtml is not valid anymore.

This is some sample code:

```
<p style='font-weight:bold; margin-bottom:15px;'>
<?php if($this->personTravelerTitle == "Herr") echo "Sehr geehrter"; 
else echo "Sehr geehrte"; ?> <?php echo $this->personTravelerTitle ?> 
<?php echo $this->personTravelerLastName ?>
</p>
```

And after I insert this HTML into the `<textarea>` it looks like this:

```
<p style="font-weight:bold; margin-bottom:15px;">
<!--?php if($this--->personTravelerTitle == "Herr") echo "Sehr geehrter"; 
else echo "Sehr geehrte"; ?&gt; <!--?php echo $this--->personTravelerTitle ?&gt;
 <!--?php echo $this--->personTravelerLastName ?&gt;</p>
```

Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: Could you show us your call to `wysiwyg` with the actual PHTML content in it, and specify what file it's in?

Comment: something is converting your PHP code to comments. But there's not enough info here to tell what. Is this your own system or a third party CMS that you're using? Also, why are you putting PHP code into an input form in the first place?? Most cases I can think of where you'd want to do this, it generally turns out to be a bad idea anyway.

Comment: im setting contet on wysiwyg after init (on button click), but this should not be the problem because if u pass him normal string or just html with out php code in it, it works. I assume that problem is in 
"$("#txtarea").wysiwyg('setContent', somePHTML); "or jwysiwyg don't support php tags?